# Array of Objects with Periodic Data to Array of Objects with Cumulative Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm

I have the following periodic data, and I've been looking for a reference to an algorithm for building an array that returns a data set with cumulative values.

Initial Dataset:

```
{
    "entryDate": "2020-09-13",
    "dollars": 100
},
{
    "entryDate": "2020-10-25",
    "dollars": 200
},
{
    "entryDate": "2020-11-08",
    "dollars": 100
}
```

Desired Result:

```
{
    "entryDate": "2020-09-13",
    "dollars": 100
},
{
    "entryDate": "2020-10-25",
    "dollars": 300
},
{
    "entryDate": "2020-11-08",
    "dollars": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your data is coming as a sorted array by date. (if not you can sort it before using the below code)

Then you can use `reduce` to achieve what you want.

```js
const data = [
{
    "entryDate": "2020-09-13",
    "dollars": 100
},
{
    "entryDate": "2020-10-25",
    "dollars": 200
},
{
    "entryDate": "2020-11-08",
    "dollars": 100
}
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (acc.length === 0) {
     acc.push(item);
  } else {
     const dollars = acc[acc.length - 1].dollars + item.dollars;
     acc.push({
        ...item,
        dollars: dollars
     });
  }
  
  return acc;
  
  
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, also assuming sorted data.

```
let acc = 0;
for ( const datum of data ) {
  acc += datum.dollars;
  datum.dollars = acc;
}
```